# Foreach in List and return new empty list in condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have create two class as below :

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
public class Book {
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ISBNCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

Initial Data as below:

```
{
  "Id": 0,
  "Total": 2,
  "Books": [
    {
      "BookId": 1,
      "BookName": "Book A",
      "Publisher": "Peter",
      "ISBNCode": "ISBN0001",
      "PublishDate": "2022-03-03T10:19:23.9038822+00:00"
    },
    {
      "BookId": 2,
      "BookName": "Book C",
      "Publisher": "Kate",
      "ISBNCode": "ISBN0003",
      "PublishDate": "2022-02-26T10:19:23.9039301+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make the result `if PublishDate > 2022-03-01` and then only keep `BookId and PublishDate` remain property need to empty, the expected output will be

```
{
  "Id": 0,
  "Total": 2,
  "Books": [
    {
      "BookId": 1,
      "BookName": "",
      "Publisher": "",
      "ISBNCode": "",
      "PublishDate": "2022-03-03T10:19:23.9038822+00:00"
    },
    {
      "BookId": 2,
      "BookName": "Book C",
      "Publisher": "Kate",
      "ISBNCode": "ISBN0003",
      "PublishDate": "2022-02-26T10:19:23.9039301+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

For book class will have many properties and sublist in future, so I would like make a new book, just like this

```
searchResult.Books.Where(dt => dt.PublishDate > '2022-3-1').ToList().ForEach(
        b => new Book {
                BookId = b.BookId,
                PublishDate = b.PublishDate
    });
```

But I have no idea inside, can anyone advise about this ?
Thank you

Comment: One way to do it, is to create a new List (for example filteredSearchResult) and populate it in your ForEach

Comment: I got your mean, so I create the a small method like this
private Book filterBook(Book record, DateTime checkDate) {
   if (record.PublishDate > checkDate)
    return new Book() {
     BookId = record.BookId,
     PublishDate = record.PublishDate
    };
   else
    return record;
  }
But I have no idea how to use this method
 var testresult = new SearchResult() {
    Id = searchResult.Id,
    Total = searchResult.Total,
    Books = ??
   };

Comment: Another question: In your expected result, there is still the data of a book, which doesnt fulfill your date filter. Is this intended. If yes, please edit your question, to make more clear what you want to achive

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a little strange to clear properties, maybe I don't get it completely, but..
You could create a filter, which will be used with Select:

```
private static Book ClearPropertiesAfterDate(Book book, DateTime date)
{
    if(book.PublishDate > date)
        return new Book { BookId = b.BookId, PublishDate = b.PublishDate }
    else
        return book;
}

// use select to transform each item. 
// The ClearPropertiesAfterDate returns a new book (with only the id 
// and publishDate when it was released after a certain date 
// otherwise it returns the original book.

var booksFiltered = searchResult.Books.Select(dt =>
                        ClearPropertiesAfterDate(dt, '2022-3-1')).ToList();
```

'2022-3-1' should be a DateTime? Just should how you could transform items, didn't tested it in visualstudio or fiddle thingy